# Javascript:void(0) error with installed extension

Tags: extensions, javascript, menu

I integrated this extension [Free Magento Custom Menu](http://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension.html) for my top navigation but when I add it and I would like to navigate over the menu I have this error message "javascript:void(0)" for redirection.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the file `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webandpeople/custommenu/top.phtml`.
Replace these lines:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span>Menu</span>
</a>
```

With

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
    <span>Menu</span>
</a>
```

or better yet:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Menu');?></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Ha. Amazing plugin support. Also - default/default?!

Comment: @philwinkle Yeah...that's where they placed the file.

Comment: Should be base/default, no?

Comment: It actually works this way also. The only way it doesn't work is if your current interface (package) is not default. The hierarchy is {interface}/{theme}, {interface}/default, base/default. So if the interface name is default (as it is in most cases) this could work. But I agree. The file should be placed in base/default. for the newer versions, but maybe the extension is compatible with older versions, before base/default existed. (before CE 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

This particular plugin uses the pattern of providing links within the `rel` attribute of the anchor tag, and providing `void(0)` for the `onclick` event.

[Their demo site](http://green-magento-template.web-experiment.info/) seems to work fairly well.

This leads me to believe that the extension is not installed correctly and you are missing a Javascript include file that would remap these `rel` attrs to `href`.

The `void(0)` pattern is used to prevent the browser from reloading the page via the click on the element - usually to inject some functionality in between the click on the DOM element and the page load.

Aside from not being best-practice I feel like there may be SEO implications to using this pattern - I highly suggest you look into another navigation plugin over on Magento Connect.

For further support, contact the plugin creator.